# Kotlin version issues: The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0. Not working by changing the version in build.gradle

Tags: java, android, react-native, kotlin, gradle

I am getting kotlin version incompatibility issue. I had made changes to my project level build.gradle file then also the issue persist.

I am getting the following error after Gradle sync:
C:/Users/ADMIN/.gradle/caches/8.0.1/generated-gradle-jars/gradle-api-8.0.1.jar!/META-INF/configuration-cache.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 24
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        kotlinVersion = "1.6.0"
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "19.2.0"

        if (System.properties['os.arch'] == "aarch64") {
            // For M1 Users we need to use the NDK 24 which added support for aarch64
            ndkVersion = "24.0.8215888"
        } else {
            // Otherwise we default to the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
            ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
        }
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1')
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:5.0.1")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://www.jitpack.io"
        }
        mavenCentral {
            content {
                excludeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a gradle version compatibility issue.

You can try to upgrade the kotlin version to 1.8(Modify in build.gradle).

Or downgrade the gradle version to below 7.6(Modify in project/gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties).

See more about gradle version compatibility：
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html#kotlin

Answer (score 1):

update the the kotlin version

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'
```