# I still get "Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin" error

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle

I thought that [I fixed my build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77524713/module-was-compiled-with-an-incompatible-version-of-kotlin-its-metadata-is-1-8) by adding `ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'` to build.gradle in my Android app:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
    }
}

ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

but actually I did not, and `ext.kotlin_version` did not take an effect and I still get this messages while building my app:

```
> Task :lintVitalAnalyzeRelease
e: C:/Users/dmitr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.annotation/annotation-jvm/1.6.0/a7257339a052df0f91433cf9651231bbb802b502/annotation-jvm-1.6.0.jar!/META-INF/annotation.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/dmitr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.8.22/636bf8b320e7627482771bbac9ed7246773c02bd/kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/dmitr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.8.22/636bf8b320e7627482771bbac9ed7246773c02bd/kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/dmitr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.8.22/636bf8b320e7627482771bbac9ed7246773c02bd/kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/dmitr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.8.22/1a8e3601703ae14bb58757ea6b2d8e8e5935a586/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
```

What I missed when I thought that I fixed my build is that these messages appear only when I do a clean build and do not appear in subsequent builds.

The build succeeds:

```
> Task :createDebugBundleListingFileRedirect
> Task :bundleDebug
> Task :bundle

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 7s
88 actionable tasks: 88 executed
```

and the app works well enough on an Android device.

What should I with these messages? Is it safe to ignore them?

Probably I specified some wrong version with ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'?

**EDIT1**

Added the following to my `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0"))
```

or

```
dependencies {
    implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.6.0"))
```

removed `C:\Users\dmitr\.gradle\caches` directory and my build output directory, rebuilt the project and got the same messages.

Honestly I still do not understand well enough is it safe to ignore these messages or not.

Also did [the following experiment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75626057/kotlin-version-issues-the-binary-version-of-its-metadata-is-1-8-0-expected-ver) with this annoying madness:

```
classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.0")
```

And looks like I followed all the steps from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699823/module-was-compiled-with-an-incompatible-version-of-kotlin-the-binary-version-o).

What else can be wrong?

Comment: kotlin docs - https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew18.html#usage-of-the-latest-kotlin-stdlib-version-in-transitive-dependencies - suggest to try this when version clashes happen: implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0")).. and of course, the age old invalidate caches and restart still a good option to try

Comment: @Dmitri tried but without a success, see EDIT1

Answer (score 0):

Looks like updating Gradle from 7.3.1 to 7.4.1 and updating Gradle wrapper finally helped.